# Getting Invalid spatial reference Error from ArcGIS Runtime SDK for WPF

Tags: arcgis-10.1, c#, query, arcgis-runtime-sdk-wpf

I am getting the error:

> Invalid spatial reference. Spatial reference must match map's spatial
>   reference. Clear the map layers collection prior to changing the
>   spatial reference

when I try to Zoom in on a feature I have selected in an infogrid.

I will try to explain what I am doing and my code will be at the bottom of this question. 
I have an application that allows the user to map whatever account they are viewing based on the account number. The query is working and is showing up in the infogrid, but it is not being marked on the map with a renderer like it should and it will not allow me to zoom in and will give the message stated above.

The odd thing is, this works perfectly as long as I allow the user to click a button to query. The code is almost identical. The only thing is that the results are not displayed as soon as the map is loaded. I am going to put the code that works and the code that doesn't.

C# code (Not working):

This code is fired when the user clicks a button on a DIFFERENT control.

```
public void ShowMap(string account_num, string street, string city, string state, string zip)
        {
            LocateAccount(account_num);
        }

        void LocateAccount(string account_num)
        {

            _accountGraphicsLayer.Graphics.Clear();


            QueryTask queryTask = new QueryTask("http://xx.x.xxx.xxx/arcgis/rest/services/Calvert_City_Test/MapServer/2");
            queryTask.ExecuteCompleted += ShowMapLocatorTask_AccountToLocatonCompleted;
            queryTask.Failed += ShowMapQueryTask_Failed;

            var dirty = DateTime.UtcNow;
            Query query = new Query();
            query.OutFields.Add("*");
            query.ReturnGeometry = true;
            query.Where = "CIS_METR LIKE '%" + account_num + "%'";
            query.OutSpatialReference = MyMap.SpatialReference;
            queryTask.ExecuteAsync(query);
        }

        private void ShowMapLocatorTask_AccountToLocatonCompleted(object sender, ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.QueryEventArgs args)
        {
            // Clear previous results
            AccountDataGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            GraphicsLayer graphicsLayer = MyMap.Layers["Account"] as GraphicsLayer;
            graphicsLayer.ClearGraphics();

            // Check for new results 
            FeatureSet featureSet = args.FeatureSet;
            if (featureSet.Features.Count > 0)
            {
                // Add results to map
                foreach (Graphic resultFeature in featureSet.Features)
                {
                    //resultFeature.Symbol = ResultsFillSymbol;
                    graphicsLayer.Graphics.Add(resultFeature);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No features found");
            }
        }

        public void ShowMapQueryTask_Failed(object sender, TaskFailedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Query failed: " + e.Error);
        }
```

C# Code (Working):

This code is fired when the user clicks a button that is inside my mapping control.

```
private void AttributeSearchButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            RunQuery();
        }

        private void RunQuery()
        {
            _attributeQueryGraphicsLayer.Graphics.Clear();

            QueryTask queryTask = new QueryTask("http://xx.x.xxx.xxx:6080/arcgis/rest/services/Calvert_City_Test/MapServer/2");
            queryTask.ExecuteCompleted += GeneralQueryTask_ExecuteCompleted;
            queryTask.Failed += GeneralQueryTask_Failed;

            var dirty = DateTime.UtcNow;
            Query query = new Query();
            query.OutFields.Add("*");
            query.ReturnGeometry = true;
            query.Where = "CIS_METR LIKE '%" + QueryParametersTextbox.Text + "%' OR COMMENTS LIKE '%" + QueryParametersTextbox.Text + "%'";
            query.OutSpatialReference = MyMap.SpatialReference;               
            queryTask.ExecuteAsync(query);



        }

        // Draw results when query is complete
        private void GeneralQueryTask_ExecuteCompleted(object sender, ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.QueryEventArgs args)
        {
            // Clear previous results
            QueryDataGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            GraphicsLayer graphicsLayer = MyMap.Layers["QueryResults"] as GraphicsLayer;
            graphicsLayer.ClearGraphics();

            // Check for new results 
            FeatureSet featureSet = args.FeatureSet;
            if (featureSet.Features.Count > 0)
            {
                // Add results to map
                foreach (Graphic resultFeature in featureSet.Features)
                {
                    //resultFeature.Symbol = ResultsFillSymbol;
                    graphicsLayer.Graphics.Add(resultFeature);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No features found");
            }
        }

        // Notify when query fails
        private void GeneralQueryTask_Failed(object sender, TaskFailedEventArgs args)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Query failed: " + args.Error);
        }
```

XAML:

Everything in the XAML is set up exactly the same, it just uses different IDs.